# Real valued random variable definition

Tags: probability-theory

There are already questions for this topic, but they are on other issues.

My textbook says

> Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F}, P)$, a random variable on the probability space is a function $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that for every scalar $\lambda$ the set
>   $$\{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \leq \lambda\}$$
>   is an event, i.e., it belongs to the collection $\mathscr F$.

This question is so simple, but why do we use some scalar $\lambda$ in the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your definition says, $X$ maps to the set of real numbers (or scalars) $\mathbb R$. So $X(ω)$ lies in $\mathbb R$ and therefore it can be "compared" with scalars.

Now, the reason that only intervals of the form $(-\infty, λ)$ are considered is that these intervals (or half lines) generate the Borel $σ$-algebra in $\mathbb R$. Remember that you started from a $σ$-algebra $(\mathcal F)$ and you want to end up in a $σ$-algebra (Borel $σ$-algebra in $\mathbb R$.)